# Scala Slick: Exception on using groupBy on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, scala, slick-2.0

I am using MySQL with slick 2.1. 
I have a table `Users`, `Cars` which store the cars that an user owns, `garages` that stores the car's information and a table `User_contact` to store the contact details of the users.

I want to get user information using his id, contact details and number of cars and garages he owns. For that I wrote the following code:

```
user.filter( _ .id === id).leftJoin(cars).on {
      case (user, car) => user.id === car.userId
    }.leftJoin(garage).on {
      case ((_, car), garage) => car.id === garage.carId
    }.leftJoin(userContacts).on {
      case (((user, _), _), contact) => user.id === contact.userId
    }.groupBy { case (((user, _), _ ), contact) => (user, contact) }.map {
      case ((user, contact), usrGroup) => (usr.id, usrGroup.map { case (((_, cars), _), _ ) => cars.id }.length, usrGroup.map { case (((_, _), garage), _) => garage.id }.length, contact)
    }
```

This leads to

```
Execution exception[[SlickException: No type for symbol s44 found in {description: Option[$anon$1/VARCHAR(254)], first_name: Option[$anon$1/VARCHAR(254)], timezone_code: Option[$anon$1/VARCHAR(254)], profile_id: Option[Long/BIGINT], id: Int/INTEGER, dob: Option[Date/DATE], gender: Option[$anon$1/VARCHAR(254)], email_id: $anon$1/VARCHAR(254), inset: Option[$anon$1/VARCHAR(254)], last_name: Option[$anon$1/VARCHAR(254)], created_time: Timestamp/TIMESTAMP}]]
```

during runtime. Can somebody help in pointing out what can be reason? It works fine, if I group by only by `user` but not if I add `contact` field.

Comment: Try to activate the slick debug mode and post the generated SQL request too.